# How can display driver version be obtained on the Mac?

Tags: macos, driver

How can the display driver version be programatically obtained on the Mac?

---

Related:

- [Programmatically get processor details from Mac OS X](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/853798/programmatically-get-processor-details-from-mac-os-x)

Comment: I'm looking to get the version programatically. Thanks.

Comment: Worst case you can `popen("system_profiler ...")`, but there must be an API for this...

Answer (score 3):

Look a IOKit and the IORegistryExplorer application.

Specifically, you'll want to search IOKit for devices with a name of 'display' and you'll get the device node from which you can pull data. Use the IORegistryExplorer application to see what sort of attributes are available from that object, and what types of data they are, etc.

Answer (score 2):

**Apple** -> **About This Mac** -> **More Info**

Expand the **Hardware** drop-down and click on the **Graphics/Display** option

This will display all the information about the current video card and driver info.

Comment: That's programatically? Sounds a bit … unusual. What language are you using for that ;)

Comment: not programatically. Guess I answered before the question was updated.

Answer (score 0):

From the command line run `system_profiler`. Get the same data as t[he GUI based answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/821133/how-can-display-driver-version-be-obtained-on-the-mac/821145#821145).